# How to get response of snmptrap v2 with private mib

Tags: java, snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j, snmp-trap

the private mib is define as below:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.49763.1.2.5
userTrap NOTIFICATION-TYPE 
OBJECTS{
userName,
userType,
userStatus
}
STATUS current
DESCRIPTION
"Traps of user operation"
::={stationTrap 2}
```

*My code is supported by SNMP4J as below*

```
public void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent CREvent) {  
        if (CREvent != null && CREvent.getPDU() != null) {
           try {  
            Vector<? extends VariableBinding> recVBs = 
            CREvent.getPDU().getVariableBindings();
              for (int i = 0; i < recVBs.size(); i++) {
                    VariableBinding recVB = recVBs.elementAt(i);
                    System.out.println(recVB.getOid() + " : " + 
            recVB.getVariable());                   
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

I want to know what is the response type of this trap ,how to get userName and userType in the OBJECTS

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {

        }` don't silently swallow your exceptions

Comment: Ok,but this problem still confused me